# Dificuldade pra pegar um elemento do json com php

Tags: php, json

Tenho o seguinte resultado em json:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [charges] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [code] => 70082972
```

Gostaria de saber como eu faço pra pegar o elemento **code** com php.

Tentei:

```
echo $data["charges"][0]["code"];
echo $data->charges->code;
```

Mas sem sucesso.

Comment: já tentou: `echo $data["data"]["charges"][0]["code"];` ?

Comment: acabei de tentar e deu foi certo. Posta como resposta pra eu ti avaliar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou digitar um das chaves do `arrays` que é `data` e a solução final:

```
echo $data["data"]["charges"][0]["code"];
```